# Button setup to show another but not document.getElement not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the html and js below to show and hide an image and button on click, I know this is a simple mistake but can't work out where it is, any help?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a id="imgbutton" class="btn btn-success form-control" style="display:block" onClick="streetviewshow();">Click here to see the street view image</a>
            <a id="imgbuttonhide" class="btn btn-success form-control" style="display:none" onClick="streetviewhide();">Click here to hide the street view image</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function streetviewshow(){
        document.getElementById('showimg').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('imgbutton').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('imgbuttonhide').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function streetviewhide(){
        document.getElementById('showimg').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('imgbutton').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('imgbuttonhide').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: There is no element in the DOM having `id` being used in `script`

Comment: But there is? so I am not sure why this is erroring

Comment: `document.getElementById('showimg').style.display = 'block';` will throw the error -> add showimg element or remove this line

Comment: That worked thanks loads